# Is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, riemann-sum

> **Problem:** In a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty,$ $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}.$$

Determine if the sequence is convergent or divergent and, if convergent, compute its limit.

---

Honestly, I don't really know where to start. In my book they state the following regarding convergence for sequences:

The sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is said to converge with limit $a$ if 
$\forall \ \varepsilon >0 \ \exists \ N_\varepsilon:n>N_\varepsilon\Rightarrow|a_n-a|<\varepsilon.$

What does this even mean? I know the symbols but I can't intuitively understand it and apply it on my problem.

Comment: Hint: how many terms are there in the sum?  Can you find an upper bound for the individual terms? What does this imply for the upper bound on the sum?

Comment: Well, $\sum \frac 1{k^2}=\frac {\pi^2}6$ so that sum converges.  So...what does that tell you about the tail of the infinite sum?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - There are $n-1$ terms right? Would an upper bound be  $1/n^2$? I'm not reallt sure about your last question.

Comment: @parseval There are $n$ terms, actually.  If there are $n$ terms, all of them no larger than $\frac1{n^2}$, how large can the sum be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is convergent and the limit is $0$, because:

$$0\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\le n\times\frac {1}{n^2}=\frac {1}{n} $$

and both the sequence $0$ and $\frac {1}{n}$ converge to $0$.

Comment: How do you know this: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\le n\times\frac {1}{n^2} \ ?$$

Comment: @Parseval There are $n $ terms, and each of them is of the form $\frac {1}{(n+k)^2}\le\frac {1}{n^2} $

Comment: @Parseval: it's trivial: $\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - Ah, yes ofcourse. Thanks.

Comment: But can't one just say that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\le \frac {1}{n^2}$$ without the $n$? It still approaches 0.

Comment: @Parseval We need $n$ because we have $n$ terms in the sum, and *each* is smaller than $\frac {1}{n^2} $.

Comment: I still don't understand. If each term is already smaller than $1/n^2$, then why bother multiplying with $n$ to make it even bigger? It feels unnecessary.

Comment: @Parseval But... you have a *sum* there. If each addend is smaller than something, it doesn't mean that the whole sum is smaller than that... Think about this: if x and y are smaller than 1, can you claim that x+y is smaller than 1? No, but you *can* claim that it is smaller than 1+1, i.e. 2×1.

Comment: @user8734617- Best explanation. It's all clear now, thanks! Here, have my uppvote.

Comment: @Parseval Glad to help. Please look at the other answers too, each is instructive in its own way.

Comment: Absolutely, I always do :)

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} =\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{n})^2}\right) \to0$$ since by Riemann sum. $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{n})^2} \to\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$$

Comment: @user8734617 updadate has been done any way reload your page

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
so
$$
0\leq a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\leq n\times \frac{1}{n^2}\to0
$$
Alternatively
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<\infty
$$
by the integral test or cauchy condensation test. Hence
$$
0\leq a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}\to0
$$
since the partial sums are cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: I don't understand. If now you let $n\rightarrow \infty$ both of the sums will be the same and the limit will equal zero. How did you even break it apart like that?

Comment: @Parseval thus the sum is zero

Comment: Ok, I understand. But how did you break up the sum like that? I don't see the arithmetic behind it.

Comment: @Parseval try to write down the terms the LHS start from 1/(n+1) to 1/(2n) at the RHS we have a sum from 1 to 1/(2n) minus a sum from 1 to 1/n.